# Query filter assign sub query to one field value in Drupal View

Tags: views, hooks

I have stuck in this issue from the last two days.

Please help.

I want to assign the following query .

```
$qr = "( select subconfigcode.field_subconfigcode_value AS configcode FROM node  node LEFT JOIN  field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio  select_parent_configuratio ON node.nid = select_parent_configuratio.entity_id AND (select_parent_configuratio.entity_type = node AND select_parent_configuratio.deleted = 0) LEFT JOIN  node  select_parent_configuratio_node ON select_parent_configuratio.field_select_parent_configuratio_nid = select_parent_configuratio_node.nid LEFT JOIN  field_data_field_subconfigcode  subconfigcode ON select_parent_configuratio_node.nid = subconfigcode.entity_id AND (subconfigcode.entity_type = 'node' AND subconfigcode.deleted = '0') WHERE (( (select_parent_configuratio.field_select_parent_configuratio_nid = node_field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio.nid) )AND(( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('offering')) ))) ORDER BY node.created DESC, configcode ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0)";
```

to

one view's field value.

I have used the following code.

```
 function general_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
        $qr = " ( select subconfigcode.field_subconfigcode_value AS configcode FROM node  node LEFT JOIN  field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio  select_parent_configuratio ON node.nid = select_parent_configuratio.entity_id AND (select_parent_configuratio.entity_type = node AND select_parent_configuratio.deleted = 0) LEFT JOIN  node  select_parent_configuratio_node ON select_parent_configuratio.field_select_parent_configuratio_nid = select_parent_configuratio_node.nid LEFT JOIN  field_data_field_subconfigcode  subconfigcode ON select_parent_configuratio_node.nid = subconfigcode.entity_id AND (subconfigcode.entity_type = 'node' AND subconfigcode.deleted = '0') WHERE (( (select_parent_configuratio.field_select_parent_configuratio_nid = node_field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio.nid) )AND(( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('offering')) ))) ORDER BY node.created DESC, configcode ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0)";

        $query->add_where(1, "node_field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio__field_data_field_subconfigcode.field_subconfigcode_value",  $qr);

    }
```

But, it is returning the following where query.

```
where node_field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio__field_data_field_subconfigcode.field_subconfigcode_value = '( select subconfigcode.field_subconfigcode_value AS configcode FROM node  node LEFT JOIN  field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio  select_parent_configuratio ON node.nid = select_parent_configuratio.entity_id AND (select_parent_configuratio.entity_type = node AND select_parent_configuratio.deleted = 0) LEFT JOIN  node  select_parent_configuratio_node ON select_parent_configuratio.field_select_parent_configuratio_nid = select_parent_configuratio_node.nid LEFT JOIN  field_data_field_subconfigcode  subconfigcode ON select_parent_configuratio_node.nid = subconfigcode.entity_id AND (subconfigcode.entity_type = \'node\' AND subconfigcode.deleted = \'0\') WHERE (( (select_parent_configuratio.field_select_parent_configuratio_nid = node_field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio.nid) )AND(( (node.status = \'1\') AND (node.type IN  (\'offering\')) ))) ORDER BY node.created DESC, configcode ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0) ')
```

I want to get the query in the following format.

```
 where node_field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio__field_data_field_subconfigcode.field_subconfigcode_value = ( select subconfigcode.field_subconfigcode_value AS configcode FROM node  node LEFT JOIN  field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio  select_parent_configuratio ON node.nid = select_parent_configuratio.entity_id AND (select_parent_configuratio.entity_type = node AND select_parent_configuratio.deleted = 0) LEFT JOIN  node  select_parent_configuratio_node ON select_parent_configuratio.field_select_parent_configuratio_nid = select_parent_configuratio_node.nid LEFT JOIN  field_data_field_subconfigcode  subconfigcode ON select_parent_configuratio_node.nid = subconfigcode.entity_id AND (subconfigcode.entity_type = 'node' AND subconfigcode.deleted = '0') WHERE (( (select_parent_configuratio.field_select_parent_configuratio_nid = node_field_data_field_select_parent_configuratio.nid) )AND(( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('offering')) ))) ORDER BY node.created DESC, configcode ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0)
```

I want to get query without the single quote assigned for sub query and remove extra slashed added to each value.

Please help.